# What does $m(v\cdot d/dr)v$ means?

Tags: derivatives, notation, partial-derivative

I dont understand the meaning of $$m\left(\vec v \frac \partial {\partial \vec r}\right)\vec v$$ What does $\dfrac \partial {\partial \vec r}$ operate on? Why is it in brackets?

Comment: Can you provide context? for example, where you saw this (ex if on a website, then please link it. If on a book, then attach an image)

Comment: In the title you wrote "v*d/dr", in the question body it is $\vec v \frac{\partial}{\partial\vec r}$. Please be precise in the notation. Most likely this should read $\vec v \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial\vec r}$. Which one is it?

Comment: "Which one is it" The latter. I wasn't sure this site supported formating in titles.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like you need to take the scalar product first. Say $\vec r=(x,y,z)$ and $\vec v=(v_x,v_y,v_z)$, then
$$m(\vec v\frac{\partial}{\partial\vec r})\vec v=m(v_x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+v_y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+v_z\frac{\partial}{\partial z})\vec v\\=mv_x\frac{\partial\vec v}{\partial x}+mv_y\frac{\partial\vec v}{\partial y}+mv_z\frac{\partial\vec v}{\partial z}$$
Note that the final answer is a vector:
$$m(v_x\frac{\partial v_x}{\partial x}+v_y\frac{\partial v_x}{\partial y}+v_z\frac{\partial v_x}{\partial z})\hat x\\+m(v_x\frac{\partial v_y}{\partial x}+v_y\frac{\partial v_y}{\partial y}+v_z\frac{\partial v_y}{\partial z})\hat y\\+m(v_x\frac{\partial v_z}{\partial x}+v_y\frac{\partial v_z}{\partial y}+v_z\frac{\partial v_z}{\partial z})\hat z$$

Comment: I know that. But how can i derive from behind the bracket?

Comment: @CrabCrown I've added the last step as well.